# Trying to pass java member function as a var

Tags: clojure

If I run the following code in the REPL

```lisp
(let [f '.startsWith] (f "abab" "a"))
```

it is evaluated to "a" instead of 'true'. Could someone please explain me this surprising result?

Actually, the real code, I want to make work is the following.

```lisp
(defn set-up-bean! [bean functions-and-parameters]
  (doseq [[f p] functions-and-parameters]
    (f bean p))
  (.init bean))
```

What I want to achieve is, to make the following two function calls do the same thing.

```lisp
(set-up-bean! bean [['.setMember "a"]])
```

and

```lisp
(do
  (.setMember bean "a")
  (.init bean))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One conventional approach is to use an anonymous function

```
(let [f (fn [a b] (.startsWith ^String a ^String b))] (f "abab" "a"))
```

...as this lets you type-hint parameters as-needed. You might also consider [memfn](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memfn):

```
(let [f (memfn startsWith String)] (f "abab" "a"))
```

In any event -- dot notation is syntactical sugar for interop, rather than providing real callable functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I run `(let [f (memfn startsWith)] (f "abab" "a"))` I got the following error. ArityException Wrong number of args (2) passed to: user/eval908/f--910  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)

Comment: Yes -- the original example with `memfn` was missing an argument. Please see the current edits, which are copy-and-paste tested.

Comment: To be a little more precise, you might say that `(.startsWith ...)` is syntax sugar for `(. startsWith ...)`, and `(. ...)` is a special form, not a function. You can't store a special form in a variable and "call" it from there, just like you can't store a macro in a variable and "call" it. A special form tells the compiler "generate some special code here rather than the normal code for a function call".